# FluidApp notifications are not working

Tags: fluid.app

I can't seem to make the notifications in fluid app work.

The checkbox `Allow sites to display notifications` is checked.

I also tried to check if it worked via userscript but had no luck with that either.

```
window.fluid.showUserNotification({
    title: "title",
    subtitle:"subtitle",
    description: "informText",
    sound: "Basso",
    onclick: function() { alert(1); }
});
```

I also tried to paste that directly into the console that too didn't work.

I'm using MacOS High Sierra. I'm also sure that the notifications don't work on MacOS Sierra as well.

Is it just me? Or do the notifications not work in FluidApp for "newer" MacOS versions?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I had notifications working in Sierra, but now that I've updated my machine to High Sierra, notifications don't work.  Not sure what I changed.